Make manim videos without time gap between animations
I am writing code where I want to simulate three circles moving according to an array 'positions'. I load the positions from a file, but that is not the issue. The issue is that with this code, there is always a "time gap" between animations. But I want a continuous smooth video. How can I do it? The code is below.
    radii=[Rb/10, Rc/10, Rc/10]
    positions=positions/10
    # Define initial positions for the circles
    i=0
    initial_position = [
    LEFT*positions[0,0,i]+UP*positions[0,1,i],
    LEFT*positions[1,0,i]+UP*positions[1,1,i],
    LEFT*positions[2,0,i]+UP*positions[2,1,i],
    ]
    # Create three circles with different colors
    circles = [Circle(color=BLUE, radius=radii[index], fill_opacity=1).shift(pos) for index,pos in enumerate(initial_position)]

    # Add the circles to the scene
    for circle in circles:
        self.add(circle)


    for i in range(current_N):

        # Define new positions to move the circles to
        new_positions = [
        LEFT*positions[0,0,i]+UP*positions[0,1,i],
        LEFT*positions[1,0,i]+UP*positions[1,1,i],
        LEFT*positions[2,0,i]+UP*positions[2,1,i],
        ]

        # Create animation for moving the circles
        animations = [
            circle.animate.move_to(new_pos) for circle, new_pos in zip(circles, new_positions)
        ]

        # Play the animations
        self.play(*animations)


Normally, there is no time gap when you don't use self.wait(). You could use "linear" as rate_func, see https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.utils.rate_functions.html. Then this should look like a linear animation.

@CodingWithMagga Yes, I tried it it works. Thanks!

The problem can be solved - as CodingWithMagga has suggested - by using the rate_func option in the animate command. Here is how you can modify the command:
animations = [circle.animate(rate_func=linear, run_time=0.01).move_to(new_pos) for circle, new_pos in zip(circles, new_positions)]

